# Looking for a mingw-w64 build of gcc that includes mudflap

Tags: gcc, mingw-w64

I'm trying to debug a segfault in some code built with mingw-w64's version of gcc. Since no Windows build of gcc includes the Address Sanitizer, I've been looking for a version prior to 4.9 that would allow me to use [Mudflap](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging) instead.

(It has to be 4.8 or earlier, since Mudflap was removed from gcc in 4.9 - see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging)

I've tried using downloads of 4.8.1 and 4.6.4 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/ - but my builds all fail with `cc1plus.exe: fatal error: mf-runtime.h: No such file or directory`.

I have tried using the original MinGW as well, but 4.5 as downloaded from
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version4/gcc-4.5.0-1/
just fails silently with error code 1.

Is there any site that still hosts a mingw-w64 build of gcc old enough to include mudflap? Preferably with SEH threads instead of SJLJ. If not, is there anywhere I can download a mingw-w64-compatible set of libraries and headers to install mudflap to work with an existing build?

Comment: Instead of trying some ancient gcc versions, have you tried tools like Dr. Memory?

Comment: @ssbssa I'd never heard of Dr. Memory. I'll google for it, but do you have a link you could post just in case?

Comment: [Dr. Memory](https://drmemory.org/)